# Unable to put a marker on the requested map image

Tags: android, google-maps

```
I want to have an image of a map of location whose latitude and longitude are known. So I use the code below-:

String src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=600x600&sensor=false";
Picasso.with(this).load(src).into(myEventMapImg);
```

Fine but I want to put a marker at that particular location in map image, how to do that. This is not map , it is image of map.

Comment: My dear sirs , I again repeat that this is not a map , this is an image of map that I am requesting using google map.

Comment: I also tried this but of no use-:
String src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude +
                "&zoom=13&markers=icon:http://images.clipartpanda.com/google-maps-location-icon-106061d1393485112t-tear-drop-status-bar-google-maps-icon.png" +
                "&size=600x600";

Answer (score 0):

Sample for placing marker on particular location :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LatLng source;
    private Marker sourceMarker, destiMarker;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> destiLatLong;
    private int count = 0;
    // private PolylineOptions lineOptions;
    private BeanRoute route;
    ArrayList<LatLng> points;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private ArrayList<MapsDirection> MapsDirectionList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (map == null) {
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        MapsDirectionList = new ArrayList<MapsDirection>();
        source = new LatLng(new Double("22.3000"), new Double("70.7833"));
        sourceMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(source).icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        destiLatLong = new ArrayList<LatLng>();


        destiLatLong.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("21.7542"), Double
                .parseDouble("70.6222")));


        destiLatLong.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("23.0300"), Double
                .parseDouble("72.5800")));


        destiLatLong.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("21.1700"), Double
                .parseDouble("72.8300")));


        destiLatLong.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("22.5667"), Double
                .parseDouble("88.3667")));


        destiLatLong.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("28.6100"), Double
                .parseDouble("77.2300")));

        if (destiLatLong.size() > 0) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pd = Utils.showProgressDialog(MainActivity.this, "Wait",
                            "Getting Direction...");
                }
            });
            showDirection();
        }
    }
```